# Как отменить window setRootViewController?

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Открываю moviePlayer через `window setRootViewController:`, в симуляторе iOS 8 отменяю так - `setRootViewController = nil;`, но в iOS 7 окно остается. Как правильно закрыть?

```
        self.moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:appFile]];

        [self.moviePlayerController.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];

        [self.moviePlayerController.moviePlayer setShouldAutoplay:YES];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(movieFinishedCallback:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:self.moviePlayerController.moviePlayer];

        [self.tableViewHeaderView.window setRootViewController:self.moviePlayerController];
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно презентовать его модально, попробуйте изменить логику работы, презентуйте его модально из нужного `UIViewController. presentViewController:completion:`, чтобы открыть, и `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:`, чтоб закрыть.

Answer (score 0):

Чую, Вы неправильно кодите, но попробуйте это:

```
[self. moviePlayerController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Bimawa, не сработало

Comment: Неправильно - это мягко сказано...